# Arizona form to allow victim to speak to defendent

Tags: criminal-law, assault

Upon an accidental argument/fight in which the husband is being told of assault for pretrial and if the wife which is the victim is wanting to talk to the husband (defendant)  then the victim should be able to request a form to allow the wife to talk directly or indirectly with husband.

How does the wife go about getting the prosecutor to have a signed form which allows consent of talk of see each other.   What is this form called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be the prosecutor that makes the decision.

When someone is charged with domestic violence a judge, during arraignment, will make a determination if the defendant will be released or not. If the defendant is released the judge will set the conditions of that release. As part of those release conditions, the judge, generally, will enter a no-contact order preventing the defendant from having any contact with the victim.

If the defendant and the victim wish to have contact then  a Motion to Modify the Conditions of Release will need to be submitted to the court. I believe the victim has to initiate such a motion.

Here is a link for how the [City of Tucson describes the process](https://www.tucsonaz.gov/prosecutor/victims-domestic-violence).